# Run a python script that uses pandas with C#

Tags: python, c#, pandas

I am wanting to run a python script using C#. I am able to run a sample script that creates a csv with the code below just fine. If I try to run a script that includes importing the pandas library (or any library) the code no longer works. Is there a way to use C# to run a python script that includes importing libraries? Thank you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace python
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string filename = @"PATH TO PYTHON EXECUTABLE";
            string arguments = @"PATH TO PYTHON FILE";

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = filename, // need full path
    Arguments = arguments, // need full path
    UseShellExecute = false
};

Process.Start(startInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you run the python script directly from command line using python interpreter? if running from command line fails too, means you need to install pandas package in your python installation.

```
pip install pandas
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am using an anaconda environment. My filename and arguments are "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\python.exe" and "C:\Users\username\libtest.py" respectively. Using the Anaconda python executable. I am able to run the script from the anaconda cmd prompt with importing pandas, but am unable to get it to run from C#.
I am able to get the python os library to import and run using C#. Would the pandas library be in a different location within the Anaconda environment? Thanks!

Comment: it sounds like your anaconda environment has packages/library path for pandas setup correctly but when you run with process in C#, it is running with regular command prompt environment.  You can try uninstall pandas reinstall pandas: 
"pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas"